# Running the .feature file within the IDE does not read the cucumber runner class

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, cucumber-jvm

The heart of the matter is that within my IDE (IntelliJ), I can right click on an individual .feature file and it runs fine, but does not read any of the parameters from the Runner class. From the command line, it works fine.
`mvn clean compile test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @calculator"`

I'm using a single framework to handle multiple web apps. So each app is in a separate sub-folder.

```
+---test
     +---java
         +---com
             +---company
                +---app
                ¦   +---app1
                ¦   ¦   +---common
                ¦   ¦   +---page
                ¦   ¦   +---step
                ¦   +---app2
                ¦       +---common
                ¦       +---page
                ¦       +---step
                +---core
```

The framework will use PageObject Model so `page` will contain each page's details, `common` will be for features common across the whole app, and `step` is for the Given, When, Then steps.

In the resources folder I have a similar layout

```
+---resources
    +---com
        +---company
            +---app
                +---app1
                ¦   +---feature files go here
                +---app2
                    +---feature files go here
```

The runner class is in the main `app` folder.

```
package com.company.app;

import com.company.core.Browser;
import com.company.core._Start;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.SnippetType;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"pretty",
                "html:target/cucumber",
                "json:report/report.json",
                "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:"
        },
        tags = {"~@ignore"},
        snippets = SnippetType.CAMELCASE
)
public class _RunnerTest extends _Start {
    private static String reportFile = "report.html";
    private static String configFile = "extent-config.xml";

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
    // Stuff
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void teardown() {
        // Stuff
    }
}
```

So running via Maven command line, everything works as expected. If I right-click on a .feature file (or a scenario with it) the test(s) will run, but does not use the runner class so there is no report, and the @BeforeClass and @AfterClass are ignored.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Tried it at my end. Encounter the same issue. However wanted to know, the `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` is in runner class or stepdefination class?

Also, note that since we are running feature file directly, there is no interaction with the runner class, so code will not execute.

Comment: @AshishDeshmukh, as shown, the ```@BeforeClass``` and ```@AfterClass``` are part of the runner. All they contain at the moment is reporting calls. Ideally I'd like to put the browser startup and shut down in there too. But since the runner is not being called if run within the IDE, that would be pointless.

Comment: I think to achieve what you said (to put the browser startup and shut down), we can create separate feature for the same and use nested steps to achieve the same effect of using a runner class.

Answer (score 3):

When you run the feature file directly, it is not run using the runner. If you want your test to use the @BeforeClass and @AfterClass defined in the runner, you'll have to run the runner.

Also note that although Cucumber supports JUnits `@ClassRule`, `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` annotations, using these is not recommended, as it limits the portability between different runners;
they may not execute correctly when using the commandline or IDE
Instead it is recommended to use Cucumbers `Before`
and `After` hooks.

Answer (score 0):

For running .feature file directly from IDE you should have your stepdefinitions available in same path. If they are not in same path and are separated by packages then you must use Runner file where you can provide path to your glue code and feature files.